# Testing contracts using time from OpenZepplin library: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, openzeppelin

I increase time the same way as described in OpenZepplin samples in the test below:

```
    it("should revert claim drawing with 'Android: bad state'", async () => {
    const [owner, signer1] = await ethers.getSigners();

    let duration = time.duration.seconds(3);
    await time.increase(duration);

    await truffleAssert.reverts(
        android.claimPainting(1),
        'Android: bad state'
    );
});
```

And it fails with `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`. How can i fix it?
`time` is imported as `const { time } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");` + `"@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "0.5.15"` in `package.json`.
I also use `ethers` from hardhat, don't know if this could cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to execute Hardhat local node server and try again.
"npx hardhat node"
Hope this works on your side.

Comment: yeah, it works :) it was obvious... anyways, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Install web3 and the hardhat-web3 plugin.

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-web3 web3
```

Then add the following line to your hardhat config

```
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-web3";
```

Comment: why would i need to import web3 if i use ethers already?